# Checkbox not working laravel backpack CRUD

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

```
$this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'status',
        'label' => 'Featured item',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
    ]);
```

The generated code is following:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="hidden" value="0" name="status">
      <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1"> Featured item
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the above code for checkbox, Everything works fine, value is saving correctly in database and fetched correctly. But checkbox is not checked.

[image: The checkbox is not checked even if the value is 1.]

Comment: Hi there! What version of Backpack\CRUD are you using? Does a ```composer update``` fix it for you? I just checked the current checkbox.blade.php file and it seems to have been fixed in the meantime. Cheers!

Comment: Hi
Its 3.2 for Backpack\CRUD and laravel 5.4. No composer update didn't solve it.

Comment: Try to remove your backpack folder from the vendor and do the `composer update` again

Comment: For me, my problem was that my `$fillable` array in my model class wasn't updated after a migration had changed some of my columns. I'd remembered to add new fields to the XyzCrudController but not to the `$fillable` array.

Comment: @Ryan could you make your comment as an answer ? That was my problem (The simplest things ...) and I want to mark is a a correct answer.

Comment: @MarcBrillault Glad to hear that it helped. I wrote an answer here that you can upvote (but won't be able to accept since you weren't the original question asker): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525658/470749

Answer (score 1):

For me, my problem was that my `$fillable` array in my model class wasn't updated after a migration had changed some of my columns.

I'd remembered to add new fields to the XyzCrudController but not to the `$fillable` array.