# BackPack PageManager fields.select_page_template not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

While accessing pages or creating pages getting the following error:

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [fields.select_page_template] not found. (View: /home/ubuntu/pbc/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/inc/show_fields.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/pbc/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/inc/show_fields.blade.php) (View: /home/ubuntu/pbc/vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/inc/show_fields.blade.php)
```

Followed this solution: [Try to remove your backpack folder from the vendor and do the composer update again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526278/checkbox-not-working-laravel-backpack-crud?noredirect=1#comment72554837_42526278)

Comment: Hi there! Managed to fix this in the meantime?

Comment: Yes, created a new file with same name and replaced the file that solved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new file named PageTemplates.php and replace the existing in the app directory. After that you may copy the previous code.